# HTML page returns Undefined from API response

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, rest

I've got the following JS which is attempting to return a value from an AWS API Gateway:

```
 <script>
        fetch("https://myapi/get")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        document.getElementById("website-counter").innerHTML = data.body
        });
 </script>
```

The API GW triggers a lambda function to get a value from a DynamoDB table.
Im attempting to display the retuned value by

```
<p>
   CV Website Views: <span id="website-counter"></span><br/>
                
</p>
```

However, the "website-counter" returns an undefined value, not the required DB value.

Also, Ive set the CORS headers in the Lambda function itself. If i access the direct link to the API from AWS console, i get the retuned value from dynamodb as expected.

Comment: Make sure you've put your script tag before you close the `body` tag. (towards the end of file)

Comment: The script tag is already before the closing body tag, thanks

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to determine why `data.body` is undefined. You haven't provided the code for the API, nor a log of what `data` actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This post resolved the issue for me: [ES6 fetch function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591514/es6-fetch-function-returns-undefined)

This is now working fine:

```
     <script type ="text/javascript">
            function visitcount() {
                return fetch("https://myapi/get").then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
                }).then(function(json) {
                    return json;
                });
                                }

                visitcount().then(function(result) {
                document.getElementById("website-counter").innerHTML = result
                console.log(result);
                });
        
    </script>
```

Comment: This has a *lot* of changes which are completely redundant. It looks like the root cause of your problem is that your API *doesn't* return a JSON text with a property called `body` on it. (That is the only significant change between this and your original code I can see) That's the sort of trivial error that isn't generally useful, so you'd be better off just deleting the question instead.